# IF() Measure with variables ignoring filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure with 4 variables, the final product of which (`FixedBooleanValue`) is to return a true if 0, otherwise false.

All four variables before the `return` will filter by organisation
correctly if turned into their own measures, and it is only the final measure that appears to disregard when filtered.

Relationships here are:

`Agreement[AgreementKey]  1 - * Agreement Conditions[AgreementKey]`

`Calendar[DateKey] 1 - * 'Agreement Conditions'[DateKey]`

`Organisation[OrganisationKey 1 -* 'Agreement Conditions'[OrganisationKey]`

The measure is:

```
Discount Fixed Boolean :=
VAR Margin =
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Margin Pct] ),
        LASTNONBLANK (
            'Calendar'[ActualDate],
            AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Margin Pct] )
        )
    )
VAR Minimum =
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Minimum Pct] ),
        LASTNONBLANK (
            'Calendar'[ActualDate],
            AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Minimum Pct] )
        )
    )
VAR BaseRate =
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Base Rate Pct] ),
        LASTNONBLANK (
            'Calendar'[ActualDate],
            AVERAGE ( 'Agreement Conditions'[Discount Base Rate Pct] )
        )
    )
VAR FixedBooleanValue = Margin + Minimum + BaseRate
RETURN
    IF ( FixedBooleanValue = 0, TRUE, FALSE )
```

So for some reason filter contexts are not applied for the final `if()` and appears to behaving like something akin to a cross-join, as all agreement keys are appearing next to all organisations.

I would be grateful to be shown where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison to zero is also true when FixedBooleanValue is null/blank. Please try the following so it doesn’t return True for meaningless combinations of agreement keys and organisations

```
RETURN
  IF ( 
    NOT(ISBLANK(FixedBooleanValue)),
    FixedBooleanValue = 0
  )
```

Basically that RETURN clause will return True if FixedBooleanValue=0 and False if not. But if it is blank it returns blank (since omitting the third parameter of IF means blank).